# Use Ajax response to skip a loop iteration in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to skip a loop iteration based on the ajax response. The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to use the response from Ajax outside the
Ajax call. Currently I solved it by using the below solution but here the problem is that I'm using `async: false` which is not recommended as Ajax call is async.

```
function ajaxCallHere(name) {
    let url = '/admin/someUrl/' + name;
    var skipName = '';
    $.ajax({
        'url': url,
        'type': 'GET',
        async: false,
        'success': function (data) {
            skipName = data.skip;
        }
    });
    return skipName;
}

function getAllNames() {
    for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var skipVal = ajaxCallHere(names.fullName);

        if(skipVal == 'yes') {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your success function, have you tried: **getAllNames(data.skip)** and using that in your **getAllNames** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async/await`, since `$.ajax` returns an object that obeys the Promise protocol.

```js
function ajaxCallHere(name) {
  let url = '/admin/someUrl/' + name;
  return $.get(url);
}

async function getAllNames() {
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var data = await ajaxCallHere(names.fullName);
    if (data.skipVal == 'yes') {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```